# Text alignment in all topics on documentation is broken on Firefox

Tags: bug, status-declined, documentation

The title *17 Topics* is messing up the alignment of the first example.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/topics

This is how it is supposed to look, using Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn803.png

It's broken using Firefox 38: 
[image]

This happens on other tags as well.

Comment: [Working fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V6MZq.png) in Firefox `47.0.x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 38 is a little old, [we only support the last two proper releases of a major browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).

Comment: Little Old?  It came out over a year ago.  In internet years that is like, like... The age of dirt.

Comment: @NathanOliver when the age of clay comes? For reference.